# TypeScript: add to array if not present, or remove if present

Tags: arrays, typescript

What is the best way to *toggle* an item in an array using TypeScript.

With toggle I mean:

- If present, remove the value.
- If *not* present, add the value.

Solution with least amount of computational effort preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a generic typesafe method that "toggles" a value in an array. Note that the method returns a new array, and doesn't mutate the original one.

```
const toggle = <T extends unknown>(array: Array<T>, value: T) => {
  const newArray = array.filter((x) => x !== value)
  if (newArray.length === array.length) return array.concat(value)
  return newArray
}
```